# Weird sscanf behavior

Tags: c

I am trying to traverse string and divide words separated by tabs.

```
if(argc == 1) {
    while (argc == 1) {
        scanf("%s", ent);
        printf("<tr>");
        while (sscanf(ent, "%[^\t]%n", piece, &n) == 1 ) {           
            printf("<td>%s</td>", piece);
            ent += n;
        }
        printf("</tr>");
    }
}
```

When I run this code instead of `<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>`
I get `<tr><td>a</td></tr><tr><td>b</td></tr><tr><td>c</td></tr>`
 when I gave stdin of a\tb\tc\n
This implies that the position gets shifted after the inner while loop ends and the outer loop runs once. Shouldn't the inner while loop traverse all the string?  I can only use **sscanf** or **strtol** as string traverse separator.

Comment: `while (argc == 1)`... why? That's an infinite loop as-is.

Comment: its part of the requirement where it would always loop back to scanf after printf until you ctrl^c

Comment: the first if is redundant, `while (argc == 1)` already did a comparison first

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtok(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/) instead of [`sscanf(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sscanf/) if you're trying to tokenize a string:

```
char *piece = strtok(ent, "\t");
while (piece)
{
    printf("<td>%s</td>", piece);
    piece = strtok(NULL, "\t");
}
```

You should probably be using [`fgets(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) instead of [`scanf(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) to get the string input, too.

Comment: if I use strtok, the tabs are treated as a single tab, which I don't want. I would really like to use sscanf :)

Comment: Then use [`strsep(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strsep/), which can handle that case. `scanf` is *definitely* not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s"` reads a whitespace delimited string -- so in you example, the first call reads the string `a` (stopping when it sees the tab -- whitespace).  If you want to read an entire line (whitespace and all), use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not skipping the tab.  `%[^\t]%n` will span all the non-tab characters and count them, then `ent += n` will skip those, and then you'll restart at the tab.

It's easier to just ignore leading whitespace (and with html it's not a bad thing at all):

```
while (sscanf(ent, " %[^\t]%n", piece, &n) == 1 )
//                  ^ skip spaces
        printf("<td>%s</td>",piece);
        ent += n;
}
```

Or if for some reason you have to have exactly a single terminating tab,

```
while (sscanf(ent,"[^\t]%n", piece, &n) ==1) {
        printf("<td>%s</td>",piece);
        ent+=n;
        if (*ent) ++ent;
}
```

And if there's no hypercritical pedants around this is useful:

```
int scanned=0;
while ( sscanf( ent+=scanned,"%[^\t]%n%*c%n", piece, &scanned, &scanned) > 0 )
        printf("<td>%s</td>",piece);
```

Don't listen to the people who don't like `%n`, they're just `%n`ay-sayers :-)